# error in creating ticket by using osticket api_create_ticket.php

Tags: php, json, curl, osticket

I am trying to create ticket by using osticket api_create_ticket.php but I am getting response code 200. Everything is same as described in many documentation and example. I have used server ip for api key also tried my system ip. Gave write permission to the folder. But still it is not working.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php


$config = array(
    'url'=>'http://myweb.in/project1/support/api/tickets.json',
    'key'=>'3B2BADDBF72D30DBEBD6378A1DF2E6FB'
    );


    $data = array(
'name'      =>      'John Doe',
'email'     =>      'mailbox@host.com',
'subject'   =>      'Test API message',
'message'   =>      'This is a test of the osTicket API',
'ip'        =>      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   );

   function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
   function_exists('json_encode') or die('JSON support required');

   set_time_limit(30);

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.7');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   $result=curl_exec($ch);


   $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

   curl_close($ch);

   print_r($code);

   if ($code != 201)
   die('Unable to create ticket: '.$result);

   $ticket_id = (int) $result;

   ?>
```

Comment: Response code 200 means the request has succeeded.

Comment: I need response code 201

Comment: I can try it on my server. Where did you get the api from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I got it from here https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.7/blob/develop/setup/scripts/rcron.php

```
<?php


$config = array(
    'url'=>'http://myweb.in/project1/support/api/tickets.json',
    'key'=>'3B2BADDBF72D30DBEBD6378A1DF2E6FB'
    );
#check if curl is enabled
function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');

#set execution time. Make it 0 if there is no time limit
set_time_limit(60);

    $data = array(
    'name'      =>      'John Doe',
    'email'     =>      'mailbox@host.com',
    'subject'   =>      'Test API message',
    'message'   =>      'This is a test of the osTicket API',
    'ip'        =>      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
       );

   function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL NOT SUPORTED');

   set_time_limit(30);

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.7');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   $result=curl_exec($ch);

   if(preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $result, $status) && $status[1] == 200)
exit(0);
   $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

   curl_close($ch);

   print_r($code);

   if ($code != 201)
   die('Unable to create ticket: '.$result);

   $ticket_id = (int) $result;

   ?>
```

Comment: my code does not have this line,  if(preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', $result, $status) && $status[1] == 200)
exit(0);   Do you think it will make any change  ?

Comment: Check carefully this line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of $result . Below this line $result=curl_exec($ch); Add var_dump($result); exit;

Comment: it returns string(1) " ".

Comment: In the URL i provided i see the url as http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tasks/cron but your url looks like http://myweb.in/project1/support/api/tickets.json . I dont have much idea on OsTicket but its better if you look at the URL once.

Comment: Amit@ I am much familiar with php and curl. The URL i am giving is for upload data as tickets.json as mentioned in the documentation and several examples. And cron is for detecting callback.